# How can I integrate the complex function $z= xy$ over the unit circle?

Tags: complex-analysis

I know I would either have to express $xy$ in polar or find a parametrization for the unit circle in Cartesian coordinates, but that seems more awkward to do.  So I'm going with converting $xy$ into polar but I'm stuck.

Comment: Hint: Is there any symmetry?

Comment: The unit circle can be parametrized by $\phi(\theta)=(sin(\theta),cos(\theta))$, $\theta\in [0,1]$

Comment: Do you mean $z=xy$?

Comment: Yes, z = xy, and also I know the other parametrization, but in order to set up my integral I need the function to be a traditional function and not a vector function.

Comment: The function isn't vector valued ...

Comment: Are you integrating on the border of the circle or over its area?

Comment: Are you integrating with respect to arclength, $ds$, or with respect to $dz$?

Comment: With respect to dz

Answer (score 3):

Due to ambiguity in the problem statement, see both this answer and Adam Hughes' (very nice) approach below.  They make different assumptions about what the question is asking for.

The easiest way to solve this is to observe that in each quadrant $xy$ has the same values (up to sign).  Since $xy$ is positive in two regions and negative in two regions, they cancel to give $0$.

Just for fun, we can use the arc length form on the unit circle.  On the upper semicircle of the circle, the form is $\frac{dx}{y}$.  Then, on the upper semicircle, the integral is 
$$
\int_{-1}^1xy\cdot\frac{dx}{y}=\int_{-1}^1xdx=\left.\frac{1}{2}x^2\right|_{-1}^1=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}=0.
$$

A similar computation holds on the bottom semicircle.

Note: To know where the $\frac{dx}{y}$ comes from, it's from the arc length formula, namely, when you use the arc length formula, you get $\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, if you work out all the details.

Comment: Are we sure he wants integration $ds$ and not $dz$? (Honest question, I realized upon reading your answer vs mine that we each assumed different choices)

Comment: @AdamHughes No, it's not entirely clear.  However, the question does mention parametrizing the unit circle.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, that's my confusion as well, since you can do that in both situations, with the other one being $dz = d(e^{it})=ie^{it}\,dt = iz\,dt$. Glad we both think so and I'm not just crazy!

Answer (score 3):

If you want the complex way, assuming integration $dz$ rather than $ds$ (as of posting it's not clear which the op means) note that $g(z) = z^2 = (x^2-y^2) + 2ixy$ so what you are integrating is

$$\oint_{S^1} {z^2-\overline{z}^2\over 4i}\,dz$$

Because ${1\over 2i}\left(g(z) -\overline{g(z)}\right)=\text{Im}(g(z)).$

But then the integral of the analytic function ${z^2\over 4i}$ around a closed curve is $0$ and you are just left with ${i\over 4}\displaystyle\oint_{S^1}\overline{z}^2\,dz$

But then the integral is just

$$\oint_{S^1}{|z|^2\over z^2}=\oint_{S^1} {dz\over z^2}=0$$

by Cauchy's integral formula or the residue theorem, et cetera.

**Edit** Now that we're sure this is meant to be the complex way of doing things, I'll expand with the parametrization approach in the case the op doesn't know how to do winding numbers.

Write

> $$\overline{z}^2\,dz = e^{-2it}\,i e^{it}\,dt\qquad 0\le t\le 2\pi$$

which gives

$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-it}\,dt=0$$

because the exponential is periodic.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: polar coordinates: $x = r\cos \theta, y = r\sin \theta$, and $I=\displaystyle \int_{\theta = 0}^{2\pi} \int_{r=0}^1 r^3\sin\theta \cos \theta drd\theta$

Comment: Yes, so there's no way to avoid doing double integration?

Comment: As a matter of fact there is.

Comment: I think I have answered the problem without double integration below.

Comment: This is integration of an area form, but it should only be a $1$-form since it's around the border of the circle unless you're using a version of Stokes' theorem, but this also yields much different integrand.